# Format Curly Braces on Same Line in C++ VSCode

Tags: c++, format, visual-studio-code, curly-braces

I'm using the [C++ Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cpptools) for [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/) *(Visual Studio Code)*.

Currently, I have the setting `"C_Cpp.clang_format_formatOnSave"` set to `true`.

This format's my code when I save my C++ file. But the format results in curly braces on new lines rather than on the same line.

**Current C++ VSCode Formatted**

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    // ...
}
```

**What I Want C++ VSCode Formatted Code to Look Like**

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    // ...
}
```

I also have `editor.wrappingIndent` set to `"same"`.

**How can I make curly braces in C++ format on the same line in Visual Studio Code?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VS Code formatting for "{ }"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45823734/vs-code-formatting-for)

Answer (score 266, accepted):

1. Go Preferences -> Settings
2. Search for C_Cpp.clang_format_fallbackStyle
3. Click Edit, Copy to Settings
4. Change from "Visual Studio" to `"{ BasedOnStyle: Google, IndentWidth: 4 }"`

e.g.

- `"C_Cpp.clang_format_fallbackStyle": "{ BasedOnStyle: Google, IndentWidth: 4, ColumnLimit: 0}"`
- btw `ColumnLimit: 0` is helpful too, because google limit will break your code to next line when you do not need it.

If you want more:

- check https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html
- customize your functionality to "C_Cpp.clang_format_fallbackStyle" for your favor.

More detail:

English: https://medium.com/@zamhuang/vscode-how-to-customize-c-s-coding-style-in-vscode-ad16d87e93bf

Taiwan: https://medium.com/@zamhuang/vscode-%E5%A6%82%E4%BD%95%E5%9C%A8-vscode-%E4%B8%8A%E8%87%AA%E5%AE%9A%E7%BE%A9-c-%E7%9A%84-coding-style-c8eb199c57ce

Comment: If I do this, every time I "paste" che code, it add an indent to the left. Why this behaviour?

Comment: In 2019 on macOS, "Settings" is found via "Code -> Preferences -> Settings" as opposed to "File -> Preferences -> Settings".

Comment: Oh wow, I had no idea about that. Spent so much time wondering why `VSC Insiders` was putting new lines after `=` on the _same indentation_ as the _last line_. Tried `VSC Stable`, no, tried with clean settings, same thing. This super helps, also gives some nice column indentation for my `map`s too. ++

Comment: By the way, after some time, I prefer `{ BasedOnStyle: Chromium }` instead of `{ BasedOnStyle: Google, ColumnLimit: 0 }` to automatically columnize things like _vector<int> allKindsOfNums = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20 }_, while still newlining unbracketed one-liner ifs.

Comment: Is there also a way to tell the code style that it should respect my manually inserted line breaks (CLion supports that by default)?

Comment: I found it! "Keep line breaks when reformatting" (CLion) can be achieved by setting the `ColumnLimit: 0` as already suggested by this post.

Answer (score 37):

Other answers are either not full, or outdated, following below worked.

1. press **`Ctrl+,`** to open settings:
2. Search for **`C_Cpp: Clang_format_fallback Style`**
   You will see the value of **`Visual Studio`**
3. So, change from **`Visual Studio`**
   to: **`{ BasedOnStyle: LLVM, UseTab: Never, IndentWidth: 4, TabWidth: 4, BreakBeforeBraces: Attach, AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: false, IndentCaseLabels: false, ColumnLimit: 0, AccessModifierOffset: -4 }`**

*-- More details on Step 2 --* (you may skip this part)

- However the value of `Visual Studio`
  is same as
  `{ BasedOnStyle: LLVM, UseTab: Never, IndentWidth: 4, TabWidth: 4, BreakBeforeBraces: Allman, AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: false, IndentCaseLabels: false, ColumnLimit: 0, AccessModifierOffset: -4 }`
- But, we need to change one thing here, we don't want to break before braces (ex: if, for, etc.), so we need below change:
  from: `BreakBeforeBraces: Allman`
  to   `BreakBeforeBraces: Attach`

Hope that helps.

Comment: I have the exact opposite problem: the default VSC and C/C++ extension format my code without newline after curly braces. I changed styles to Visual Studio, changed BreakBeforeBraces to Allman, nothing works. I wasted 3 hours on that simple problem already and it drives me mad.

For anyone who has the same problem: if you find the solution tell me too.

Comment: I followed this tip and formatted a cpp file and it sorted all my includes alphabetically breaking my build.

Comment: @pfa It does not look like sorting is done by this answer, do you have some other rules into vscode already ?

Comment: I may well do... But no idea what setting that might be.I dabble in Vue as well as C++, Antlr.

Also, all I did was change Visual Studio to the above snippet.

Added SortIncludes: false which fixed it.

Comment: Good input for community: SortIncludes. Whatever reason you had faced issue, other will get help from your post.

Answer (score 30):

[clang-format](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html) is a standalone tool used to format C/C++ code. The [C/C++ extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cpptools) comes with it, though you have the option to specify the path to your own installed version of clang-format on your computer using the option `C_Cpp.clang_format_path`.

The clang-format style source (`C_Cpp.clang_format_style`) is set to `file` by default, which reads in a `.clang-format` file. See [this page](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html) for more information about the available style options.

Otherwise, the easiest way that you are probably looking for is to just change the option `C_Cpp.clang_format_fallbackStyle`.

The style you are looking for is probably `WebKit`.

---

Hence, your `.vscode/settings.json` file should look something like this:

```
{
    "C_Cpp.clang_format_fallbackStyle": "WebKit"
}
```

Comment: You may have to install clang-format and put the path in .vscode/settings.json; for example:`"C_Cpp.clang_format_path": "/usr/bin/clang-format-3.9"`

Comment: Thanks to your solution I got very close to solve my problem, although only **brackets** of `structs` and something else was kept on the same line, not functions.
Specifying `LLVM` as style worked like a charm.
I also changed  `"C_Cpp.clang_format_style"` instead of the fallback `"C_Cpp.clang_format_fallbackStyle"`, and everything was good.

Comment: You can also add your own `.clang-format` file in the root directory to modify and extend the formatting rules, using [this](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html) for reference on the available options.

Answer (score 19):

I noticed the currently accepted answers don't work anymore. In the latest version(1.32.3), just open the settings using `Ctrl+,`, then search for `c fallback`.

[image]

Change the above value from the default to `LLVM` and you should be good to go!

Comment: This changes the indentation to 2 spaces.

Comment: The above comment is correct, at least as of now. I'd add that the extra formatting actually also helped fit a few marginally long lines of code into a single line before printing.

Comment: @ArdentCoder @MuktadirKhan As shown in the example, you can do `{BasedOnStyle: LLVM, IndentWidth: 4}`

Answer (score 19):

Other answers are good, but it still took more time to figure out, so writing this one:

---

**Steps:**

1. Open Visual Studio Code
2. Press `Ctrl + ,`
3. Search `C_Cpp.clang_format_fallbackStyle`

You will see a value of `Visual Studio` (or, other if you have changed it before)

---

You can copy-paste, replace, with one of the below options:

1. `{ BasedOnStyle: LLVM, UseTab: Never, IndentWidth: 2, TabWidth: 2, BreakBeforeBraces: Attach, AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: false, IndentCaseLabels: false, ColumnLimit: 0, AccessModifierOffset: -2 }`
2. `{ BasedOnStyle: LLVM, UseTab: Never, IndentWidth: 2, TabWidth: 2, BreakBeforeBraces: Allman, AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: false, IndentCaseLabels: false, ColumnLimit: 0, AccessModifierOffset: -4 }`
3. `{ BasedOnStyle: LLVM, UseTab: Never, IndentWidth: 4, TabWidth: 4, BreakBeforeBraces: Allman, AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: false, IndentCaseLabels: false, ColumnLimit: 0, AccessModifierOffset: -4 }`
4. `{ BasedOnStyle: Google, IndentWidth: 4 }`
5. `LLVM`
6. `WebKit`

I am using the `1st one` in the above list, which works great for my needs.

---

To revert to before, do the same steps as above, and copy-paste, replace below one:

- `Visual Studio`

---

You could also directly copy the above values into your `\.vscode\settings.json` file, for example below line:

- `"C_Cpp.clang_format_fallbackStyle": "{ BasedOnStyle: LLVM, UseTab: Never, IndentWidth: 2, TabWidth: 2, BreakBeforeBraces: Attach, AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: true, IndentCaseLabels: false, ColumnLimit: 0, AccessModifierOffset: -2 }"`

Note:

- Since this is JSON, don't forget to have a comma at the end of the above line or before the above line, depending on if you have lines before/ after.

---

More details on clang format:

- https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html

Answer (score 19):

As of 2021 for VS Code version 1.61.0:

You do the following steps:

1. Press `ctlr + ,`
2. Search for `C_Cpp.clang_format_fallback`
3. Just change the value in the textfield from `Visual Studio` to `LLVM`

Note: just remember that `LLVM` will have a tab size of 2 units.
To change the tab size into 4 units add the following configurations instead of `LLVM` in the textfield:

```
{ 
    BasedOnStyle: LLVM, 
    UseTab: Never, 
    IndentWidth: 4, 
    TabWidth: 4, 
    BreakBeforeBraces: Attach, 
    AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: false, 
    IndentCaseLabels: false, 
    ColumnLimit: 0, 
    AccessModifierOffset: -4 
}
```

4. Close the `Settings` tab and go to your file tab press `ctrl + s` to reflect your newly saved settings.

Comment: I'd recommend saving those settings to a `.clang-format` file instead, so that anyone else who has access to the code can use them.

Comment: copy pasting that json to that tiny input field did the trick for me

Answer (score 10):

I know there's already many answers here, but here's another method, that's different. Insert the following json into your settings file, or otherwise go to settings and set `vcFormat` to be the formatter, and change the `newLine.beforeOpenBrace` settings to `sameLine`:

```json
// Braces inline:
    "C_Cpp.formatting": "vcFormat",          // (Sets formatting mode to vcFormat)
    "C_Cpp.vcFormat.newLine.beforeOpenBrace.block": "sameLine",
    "C_Cpp.vcFormat.newLine.beforeOpenBrace.function": "sameLine",
    "C_Cpp.vcFormat.newLine.beforeOpenBrace.lambda": "sameLine",
    "C_Cpp.vcFormat.newLine.beforeOpenBrace.namespace": "sameLine",
    "C_Cpp.vcFormat.newLine.beforeOpenBrace.type": "sameLine",
```

This works, without significantly changing the format of your code in other areas.

Answer (score 6):

The actual clang-format option is:

```
BreakBeforeBraces: Attach
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple way, in the File -> Preferences -> Setting, search format, in the C/C++ page under Extensions option, change the option of `C_Cpp:Formatting` from `Default` to `vcFormat`.

Answer (score 0):

In `settings.jaon` add

```json
"C_Cpp.clang_format_fallbackStyle": "{ BasedOnStyle: Google, IndentWidth: 2, ColumnLimit: 0}",
```

I have added `indent`  `2`.

For Formatting(Code Selection) you can use shortcut - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>K</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>F</kbd>.

The expected formatting will be applied to your code.

[image: VSCODE Indent settings]

Answer (score -1):

For Visual Studio 2019 (searching on google for vs2019 gave this page) you do:

> Tools > Options > Text Editor > C/C++ > Formatting > General > Default
>   Formatting Style

A quick way is to select `Google` and you get the desired result.
I think it might wipe out other customizations you put in place, so beware.

You also have custom clang-format file option there as well if you have time to research how to do that.

Comment: There is difference between  Visual Studio Code and Visual Studio

Answer (score -1):

For C# on 2019:

Options > Text Editor > C# > Code Style > Formatting > New Lines

Disable "Place open brace on new line for types" / functions, etc...