# VS Code - Brackets in the same line (K&R style) in every curly brace programming language

Tags: javascript, c++, visual-studio-code, code-formatting

I'm looking for a way to tell Visual Studio Code to always put opening bracket in the same line in every curly brace programming language.

I saw only some [extensions for JS](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode) or some (for me) [weird ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46111834/format-curly-braces-on-same-line-in-c-vscode) to do this in other languages like C++, but still if i correctly understood, they were only for specific languages. How can i achieve this 'globaly' in every language that uses curly brackets?

Or I'm just stupid and this option is somewhere is VS Code already? It is weird to me that it is so hard to change so common thing. [Only extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryannaddy.vscode-format) i found that description tells that it can do it... completely broke code formatting.