# How do I set up VSCode to NOT put curly braces on a new line?

Tags: visual-studio-code, formatting, code-formatting, platformio

Basically the opposite of this question:
[How do I set up VSCode to put curly braces on a new line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32900921/how-do-i-set-up-vscode-to-put-curly-braces-on-a-new-line)

I am working with the [PlatformIO](https://platformio.org/) extension for VSCode and whenever I format the document, I get all my curly braces misplaced on new lines, which looks horrible (coming from Java).

[Similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46111834/format-curly-braces-on-same-line-in-c-vscode), but it is asking about a specific C++ extension.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a `.clangformat` file to your project. For example:

```
---
BasedOnStyle: Google
UseTab: Never
IndentWidth: 4
TabWidth: 4
BreakBeforeBraces: Attach
AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: false
IndentCaseLabels: false
AccessModifierOffset: -4
ColumnLimit: 88
...
```

You can read about the options here:
https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html

Alternatively you can edit your vscode settings fallback style:

```
{
  "C_Cpp.clang_format_fallbackStyle": "{ BasedOnStyle: Google, IndentWidth: 4, TabWidth: 4}"
}
```

Comment: Filename must be `.clang-format` otherwise it will not be picked up