# Format for curly braces in VS Code Snipets for C/C++

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-code, code-snippets

I installed the C/C++ Snippets extension in VS Code, and it creates a snippet like this:

```
for ( ) 
{
    // your code
}
```

but I want the open brace on the keyword line:

```
for ( ) {
```

I found this topic for C/C++ formation in VS Code: "Format Curly Braces on Same Line in C++ VS Code" but it didn't solve the problem (so, the snippet extension doesn't follow the C formatting "rules" in VS Code, I guess).

I can't find any setting in the VS Code settings JSON file for this extension.

Anyone have an idea?

(In the ideal world, the curly brace for functions would remain on the next line and only braces associated with keywords would be on the same line.)

Thank you,

-Vin

Comment: Try this link https://medium.com/@nosuchstudio/formatting-curly-braces-on-the-same-line-in-c-in-vscode-c4937e1c215f

Comment: @AliJibran Sadly this did not do anything. I'm not using C# and not using Linux, so I just created the indicated JSON file and put it in the directory with the file I was editing. Restarted  VS Code, closed and opened editing file.

Comment: In vscode settings, try to search something like "CURLY" or "BRACE" it will show you the complete list. select C++ and change the settings as you desire.

Comment: try this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/50606364/4853427

Comment: @AliJibran That also didn't help - no entry. It just found the one I already changes. The article you referenced was the one I mentioned in my original post. I've made that change but it does not affect the way the snippet creates the block. Thanks for trying - I may be out of luck.

Answer (score 2):

I did some intense digging and found the name of the file that holds the snippits, then looked in all the "usual suspect" places and found it:

C:\Users\.vscode\extensions\hars.cppsnippets-0.0.14\snippets\

in this directory, there are two files: **c.json, cpp.json**

In each there are json entries for each snippit. I edited a couple in the c.json to test and they now format as I want. Thanks Ali! your suggestions got me thinking!

Comment: Outline the steps and close the question

Comment: Sadly, with an update it want back to "normal" So I've written to the author to see if he can add this behavior as a preference choice.