# remove brackets on a new line in code block ms-vscode

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-code, code-snippets, brackets

Okay, I'm stuck!
At the moment, when I pressing `tab`, my code is complemented basic constructs(e.g **if, for, while**). This snippets(*as I know*), not **formatting code**. Curly brackets inserted a new line like this:

```
if()
{
    /* code */
}
for()
{
    /* code */
}
```

It irritates me. I need this:

```
if() {
    /* code */
}
for() {
    /* code */
}
```

How do I do it? Need to change snippets or it's easier?
This **is not** a formatting of already written code, so this [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46111834/format-curly-braces-on-same-line-in-c-vscode) did not help me.

Install extension in vscode:

1. ms-vscode.cpptools
2. austin.code-gnu-global

Comment: The snippets are editable, and you can override rules. You just need to check the documentation.

Comment: Check Tools-->Options-->Text Editor-->(language)-->New Lines. If that doesn't work, check if you have a .clang-format file somewhere in the same directory or a parent directory that is controlling your auto-format settings.