# Format C/C++ code with opening curly brace on the same line

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-formatting

I am using Visual Studio Code with the C/C++ extension. 
The command Ctrl+Shift+I formats the code with opening brace on a new line like this:

```cpp
int f () 
{
   return 0;
}
```

What I want is this:

```cpp
int f() {

}
```

Is there any setting you can change to do this? If not, is there any other extension that would format the code how I want?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VS Code formatting for "{ }"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45823734/vs-code-formatting-for)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Vscode ships with a version of the [clang-format extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=xaver.clang-format). As it is described in the [vscode docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp#_code-formatting) you can add a `.clang-format` file to your workspace root that specifies style rules. How the `.clang-format` file is formatted and which rules exist can be read [here](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html).
Instead (or in addition) you can use an existing style and just configure a few options. For that you either configure the [BasedOnStyle](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html#configurable-format-style-options) property in your `.clang-format` file **or** you can set the `"C_Cpp.clang_format_style"` option in your vscode user settings.
In your case, to achieve the opening curly bracket on the same line, you can just use the [Google's C++ Style](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Function_Declarations_and_Definitions). To enable it via the vscode settings, add the following entry to your user settings:

```json
"C_Cpp.clang_format_style": "Google"
```