# How come Visual Studio Code does not support C style formatting by default?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, formatting, styles, braces

How come VSCode does not support C style formatting by default?

Meaning put curly braces on a new line instead of using same line.

For example:

```
int main()
{

}
```

instead of:

```
int main() {

}
```

I'd love to know why.

Comment: Because C programmers aren't Java-centric ? The default formatting style is Allman with most IDEs. I strongly advise you adhere to that, because the *vast* majority of the worlds C programmers certainly do.

Comment: C != javascript, the first snippet is more often used

Comment: There is an answer for C++ [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45823734/visual-studio-code-formatting-for) which needs an extension to be installed.

Comment: Are you asking the question "why did MS do this?" or "how can I configure my code format?"

Comment: Using same line is WAY better

Comment: I'm asking why VSCode / MS does not support this by default?

If you read the first line it should be fairly clear,
-"How come VSCode does not support C style formatting by default?"