# Format If-else on Different Line in C++ VSCode

Tags: c++, if-statement, visual-studio-code, format

I'm using the [C++ Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cpptools) for [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/) (Visual Studio Code).

This format's my code when I save my C++ file. But the format results in if-statement and curly braces on same lines rather than on the new line.(I have already set format Curly Braces on Same Line)

**C++ VSCode Formatted**

```
if(...){
    //...
}else if(...)
    //...
}else{
    //...
}
```

**What I Want C++ VSCode Formatted Code to Look Like**

```
if(...){
    //...
}
else if(...){
    //...
}
else{
    //...
}
```

**How can I make If-else in C++ format on the differernt line in Visual Studio Code?**

Comment: The tool uses clang-format. If you want it to behave differently, you'll need to create a `.clang-format` file and configure it to your liking and place it in the root of your project.

Answer (score 3):

You need to have C/C++ extension(just check if you have it). [Original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45823734/visual-studio-code-formatting-for)

**1st idea**

1. Go File-> Preferences -> Settings
2. Search for C_Cpp.clang_format_fallbackStyle
3. Click Edit, Copy to Settings
4. Change from "Visual Studio" to "{ BasedOnStyle: Google, IndentWidth: 4 }"

(Change from "Visual Studio" to "LLVM", "Google" or "WebKit")

Something like this:

> "C_Cpp.clang_format_fallbackStyle": "{ BasedOnStyle: Google, IndentWidth: 4, ColumnLimit: 0}"

Also check documentation: [here](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html) and [another one](https://zamhuang.medium.com/vscode-how-to-customize-c-s-coding-style-in-vscode-ad16d87e93bf)

**2nd idea**

Install C# FixFormat extension

```
View > Extension
Search "C# FixFormat"
Install
```

Shift + Alt + F

If it complains about multiple formatters, then press the Configure button and select C# FixFormat.

It is possible to go back to having open braces on a new line by going to File > Preferences > Settings. Then scroll down to Extensions, C# FixFormat configuration and uncheck Style > Braces: On Same Line

Comment: Literally the first thing they say is that they are using the C/C++ extension. And you're suggesting an indent-width setting, they are talking about a line break setting.

Answer (score 1):

The VS Code extension uses a program called clang-format to format your code. You can change how clang-format behaves by placing a `.clang-format` file in your project root and double-checking that the default style is 'file' in VS Code's settings. The setting is `C_Cpp: Clang_format_style`.

Here is a minimal `.clang-format` that gets as close to your desired output as clang-format allows.

```
BreakBeforeBraces: Stroustrup
IndentWidth:       4
SpaceBeforeParens: Never
```

It cannot remove the space before the opening brace, but I'm personally on clang-format's side on that decision. You will naturally want to peruse the documentation, https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html, to see all the options available to you.

Comment: how to apply this to javascript?

Answer (score 0):

I use this clang format and it works with me:

{ BasedOnStyle: LLVM, UseTab: Never, IndentWidth: 4, TabWidth: 4, AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: false, IndentCaseLabels: false, ColumnLimit: 0, AccessModifierOffset: -4, NamespaceIndentation: All, FixNamespaceComments: false, BreakBeforeBraces: Custom, BraceWrapping: { BeforeElse: true } }

The part that fix the problem is "BreakBeforeBraces: Custom, BraceWrapping: { BeforeElse: true }"

Comment: Please format code