# Visual Code C/C++ formatting of braces {}

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-code

In VSCode, I wanted my opening curly braces `{` to be in the same line, instead of a new line and for that I changed `C_Cpp.clang_format_fallbackStyle` from Visual Studio to LLVM, which seemed to work.

But it does this thing which I don't want, which is it formats my if-else statements like this:

```
if (condition){
    do_something()
} else {
    do_something_else()
}
```

Instead, I want it to be like this:

```
if (condition){
    do_something()
} 
else {
    do_something_else()
}
```

Basically I want each closing bracket to be on it's on line, whether it's for if-else statements or try-catch, or whatever.
How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your VS Code settings should be able to do something like
`"C_Cpp.clang_format_fallbackStyle": "{ BasedOnStyle: LLVM, BreakBeforeBraces: Custom, BraceWrapping: { BeforeElse: true }"`

For more info:
https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html
[Visual Studio Code formatting for "{ }"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45823734/visual-studio-code-formatting-for)
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/cpp-ide

Comment: @SatvikGupta Then would you mind marking it as accepted? Thanks